# suggestedAction issue with telegram

Tags: botframework, telegram-bot

I'm trying to add suggestedAction to communicate with telegram bot in this way:

```
"suggestedActions": { "actions": [ { "type": "imBack", "title": "Blue", "value": "color:blue" }, { "type": "imBack", "title": "Red", "value": "color:red" }, { "type": "imBack", "title": "Green", "value": "color:green" } ] }
```

and when user taps on button (green button, for example ) bot returns not a `value` (color:green) as expected but a `title` (Green)

With the skype bot the same code works well.

Comment: What version of the Bot Builder SDK are you using?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, I'm using rest api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how suggested actions work with Telegram. Each channel is responsible for its own implementations. You could try designing your bot so that the title is the same as what you want your bot to return, or you could try using adaptive cards instead.

Comment: @PavelSitnikov - Has your issue been resolved? Please remember to upvote this answer and mark it as correct

Comment: I achieved the desired result using _*Card_ object by _buttons_ property